# Access Google Drive via Service Accounts in React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm making a react.js dashboard with the functionality to retrieve files from drive and show it in a viwer. However I can't seem to get the files of the google drive.. I'm using a Google Service account.

Does anyone have any tips or experience with this?

I couldn't find the right documentation / example code for this problem

Comment: Does your react.js app run in the browser of the user?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.